# Android studio maven project - jar not working

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

Hello everyone I have added a jar library in my android project. It is a maven project which references another library in its pom.xml. Although the library works fine when tested in eclipse, it does not work in android studio, and gives a class not found exception. The class not found is a class in the library referenced in the pom of the jar library. Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, the other library defined in pom.xml may have been cached already so the library can be accessed from cache. If possible, add the .jar of the other library to you project as well.

But if you use gradle as your build system, it would be best if you can include the repo of the library you need instead of using it's .jar. If it is available in Maven most probably it is available for Gradle as well. You can search your library from the [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/) and find the gradle info at left bottom of the library's page.